# Convergence of a series with two parameters

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find for which $\alpha$ and $x$ the series
>   converges
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{(\sin x)^{3n}}{(n+1)^\alpha}\hspace{2 ex}\alpha>0,\hspace{1 ex}x\in\mathbb{R}$$

My work

By the ratio test I have

$$\lim_{n→∞}\left|\frac{(\sin x)^{3n+3}}{(\sin x)^{3n}}\frac{(n+1)^\alpha}{(n+2)^\alpha }\right|=\left|(\sin x)^3\right|\left(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right)^\alpha=|\sin x|^3$$

So the series converges if $|\sin x|^3<1\Leftrightarrow x\notin\left(\pi/2+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\right)\cup\left(3\pi/2+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\right)$

If $x\in\left(3\pi/2+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\right)$  the series is

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}=\frac{(-1)^{3n}}{(n+1)^\alpha}$$

It follows by the alternating series test, the series converges

Am  I right?

If $x\in\left(\pi/2+2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\right)$ the series converges?

Comment: If $\sin x =1$ the series is $\sum{1\over (n+1)^\alpha}$  When does that converge?  Similar question when $\sin x = -1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless $|\sin(x)|=1$, the series converges (absolutely) by the ratio test for any values of $\alpha$. This means that it converges absolutely for any values of $x$ that are not in the form $2\pi k \pm \pi/2$.

If $x$ is in the form $2\pi k + \pi/2$, then $\sin(x)=1$ and we are left with a typical p-series, which we know to converge for all $\alpha > 1$.

If $x$ is in the form $2\pi k -\pi/2$, then $\sin(x)=-1$ and $(-1)^{3n}=(-1)^n$, so we have an alternating series. This converges since its terms alternate in sign, approach zero, and decrease in absolute value for all $\alpha > 0$.

In summary, the series converges if:

- $x$ is not in the form $2\pi k \pm \pi/2$
- $x$ is in the form $2\pi k + \pi/2$ and $\alpha > 1$
- $x$ is in the form $2\pi k -\pi/2$ and $\alpha > 0$

What you’ve written so far looks correct; you’ve just left out the case of $\sin(x)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help